# Will the proposed 2017 budget move the responsibility of public services funding to the states?

Tags: united-states, budget

I have heard that the federal government is taking away federal funding from things like planned parenthood and meals on wheels for example. But then I'm also hearing that they are taking that funding and giving it to the states to distribute as they see fit. Did i get that right or not? And if that is the case it just becomes the states responsibility to fund those programs, right?

Comment: First of all, the press is reporting on Trump's budget proposal that he sent to Congress, and this is how he would like things done (perhaps). The responsibility for creating the actual budget belongs to Congress. It is highly unlikely that they will implement it exactly as proposed, and some speculate that this is part of Trumps negotiating style: start with an extreme position so that you can get what you want later when you compromise.

Comment: As others have stated, this isn't really answerable. We have no idea what you should be mad at. That said, the proposal doesn't just 'give the money' to the states. The proposal is actually cutting that money out of the budget. States, if they wanted to continue supporting the programs, would have to use their own budgets for that.

Comment: I have edited your question to take out the parts asking for opinion based answers. I think that now it is reasonably answerable and I have voted to reopen.

Comment: @blip - funding the military is up there in Constitution, one of the very few things Constutution explicitly designates as responsibility of Federal government... not really a very valid comparison, sorry.

Comment: @user4012 it doesn't say how much we need to fund. My point is that you arguing that because you don't like X, taxes shouldn't go towards it, is just stupid.

Comment: @blip - I know it's hard to imagine, but some people really DO view things from constitutional viewpoint. Things should be funded only that are supposed to be funded **because they can't be funded otherwise**. Defense is one; as per Constitution. Social safety or free abortions isn't one - regardless of any other reasoning. BTW, you're making assumptions that I advocate higher defense spending, which are not accurate :)

Comment: @user4012 I completely believe there are people that believe what you believe. That you feel you need to call out others as "satisfying your righteousness needs with Other People's Money" because they *don't* believe that is patronizing, petty, and not helping anything.

Answer (score 2):

> I have heard that the federal government is taking away federal funding from things like planned parenthood and meals on wheels for example. But then I'm also hearing that they are taking that funding and giving it to the states to distribute as they see fit.

The Donald Trump administration's budget proposal eliminates a program that gave block grants to states to spend based on state priorities.  Some of that money is spent on Meals on Wheels.  However, the checks are issued by the state.

The federal government also funds Meals on Wheels directly through an agency called [Administration for Community Living](http://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2017/03/18/meal-on-wheels-trump-budget-proposal-cuts/99308928/) in the Health and Human Services department.  This provides about 35% of the overall funding for Meals on Wheels.  This program is not slated for cancellation or specific cuts.  There is some speculation that it may be cut as part of a general 16% funding cut for Health and Human Services.  It's not clear if this is included or not at this time, as there are no details on the 16% funding cut.

Medicaid pays for some Planned Parenthood services.  That money already is prohibited from directly funding abortions, but the pro-life people say that it still ends up subsidizing it indirectly.  The pro-choice people dispute this.  Ignoring who is right, while states administer Medicaid, the federal government does partially pay for and regulate it.  Blocking this funding is part of the Obamacare repeal and replace bill, the [American Health Care Act of 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Health_Care_Act_of_2017).

In neither of these cases is responsibility being moved to the states.  In both cases, it is the states that currently spend the money at issue, although the federal government provides part (Medicaid) or all (block grants) of the funding.  The federal funding would simply be revoked in these cases.

There is also a proposal to block grant Medicaid to the states.  But that's separate and not under discussion in terms of Meals on Wheels or Planned Parenthood at this time.